# Getting visibility of element as false on Bitrise for Appium iOS tests

Tags: appium-ios, bitrise

I'm trying to run my iOS automation tests on bitrise, but getting results as false for visibility of each elements. However on my local machine everything is working fine, tested in headless mode as well. Please guide in case anyone has managed to solve that

Comment: I'd suggest you to Remote Desktop into the macOS build VM, and check what's going on there: https://gist.github.com/viktorbenei/c6d4fe1e68de739dbb5f4f15de76b9db

Without additional information about the issue it's impossible to tell anything more useful, but Remote Desktop lets you debug it yourself in most cases.

Comment: @ViktorBenei Thanks I managed to solve this by doing a clean git clone step on my local machine. The problem was my .app file was not launching properly

Comment: @S Bera Good catch, glad to hear you managed to find the root cause :)